# Unable to read images because of list index error

Tags: python, path, glob

I am trying to read images from a directory on my local Jupyter Notebook using the following code:

While I try the same code on Colab, it works fine but in Jupyter Notebook I get the `IndexError: list index out of range` error

What is wrong when I implement this code in jupyter notebook?

```
images = []
image_names = []
image_dir = 'flickr-30k-final/*.jpg'
for img in glob.glob(image_dir):
    x = img.split("/")
    name = x[1].split("\\") # Change the index based on the number of subdirectories you have. Index Starts from 0.
    image_names.append(name[0])
    cv_img = cv2.imread(img)
    images.append(cv_img)
```

Detailed error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_29008\3390765231.py in <module>
      5 for img in glob.glob(image_dir):
      6     x = img.split("/")
----> 7     name = x[1].split("\\") # Change the index based on the number of subdirectories you have. Index Starts from 0.
      8     image_names.append(name[0])
      9     cv_img = cv2.imread(img)
```

Comment: You need to print the value of `x` to see what it returns

Comment: Yup, I printed the value of x, seems to be an index miscalculation from my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a sample image path After you split the directory by "/" looks like:

```
flickr-30k-final\\imagename.jpg
```

the index value for the below line should be 1 and not 0

```
image_names.append(name[0])
```

Thus, your final code should look something like:

```
images = []
image_names = []
image_dir = "flickr-30k-final/*.jpg"
for img in glob.glob(image_dir):
    x = img.split("/")
    name = x[0].split("\\") # Change the index based on the number of subdirectories you have. Index Starts from 0.
    image_names.append(name[1])
    cv_img = cv2.imread(img)
    images.append(cv_img)
```

Doing so, if it runs successfully, just print the `image_names` variable and see its output, a list of all your image names should be printed

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I figured that out. Made an indexing mistake while rewriting the code form colab to jupyter notebook on local machine. Thanks for pasting the corrected code though